# Change size of UIAlertView buttons

Tags: iphone, button, uibutton, uialertview

I have three buttons in a UIAlertView, and I only want to change the size of two of them so that I can have toe first two on their own line and then the third button on it's own line..

Comment: "I have three buttons in a UIAlertView, and I only want to change two." -- Is that a question, or a statement?

Comment: I'm sorry I want to change the size of two of them but not the other. In other words I have a yes button, no button, and a cancel button,  want to change only the yes and no buttons size so there on one line and the cancel button is below them

Comment: I don't think you can change the size of `UIAlertView` buttons.

Comment: Read up on the uses of the UIAlertView as well as the HIG.  There is no good reason to change the button sizes if you are using the UIAlertView (within the HIG) for the reasons Apple suggest using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mess around in the view hierarchy and risk rejection from the app store, build your own Alert class from the ground up, or leave it the way it is.